# Error: Cannot Convert ‘Person*’ To ‘double*’ For Argument ‘1’ to ‘Double stdDev(double*, int)’

Tags: c++

My program below is attempting to calculate the standard deviation from the ages provide to created objects of the Person type.

When I attempt to run it on my local machine, and on a school server, the program runs fine.  However when I run it through Mimir, a website my school is using to test, I receive the below error message:

Error: Cannot Convert ‘Person*’ To ‘double*’ For Argument ‘1’ to ‘Double stdDev(double*, int)’

How would I begin to resolve this issue?  What am I missing, or not understanding?

Person.hpp

```
/********************************************************************* 
** Author: Stephen Boles
** Date: 11.5.17 
** Description: Assignment 6:  Person
*********************************************************************/
#ifndef PERSON_HPP
#define PERSON_HPP
#include <iostream>

using std::string;


class Person
{
    private:
        string name;
        double age;

    public:
        Person(string, double);
        string getName();
        double getAge();

};

#endif
```

Person.cpp

```
/********************************************************************* 
** Author: Stephen Boles
** Date: 11.5.17 
** Description: Assignment 7b: Standard Age
*********************************************************************/ 
//Include team Header.  
#include "Person.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

Person::Person(string x, double y)
    {
        name = x;
        age = y;
    }

string Person::getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
double Person::getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
```

stdDev.cpp

```
 /********************************************************************* 
** Author: Stephen Boles
** Date: 11.5.17
** Description: Assignment 7b:  BPerson
*********************************************************************/ 
// Include input/output stream and Team header.
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.hpp"
#include <cmath>

// Include standard namepaces
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


double stdDev(double arr[] , int size );

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 2;
    double people[2];

    Person p1("Boris", 23);
    Person p2("Malenko", 25);
    people[0] = p1.getAge();
    people[1] = p2.getAge();
    double a = stdDev(people, ARRAY_SIZE);
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;




}

double stdDev( double arr[], int size)
{
    int dataPointMean = 0;
    int mean = (arr[0]+arr[1])/size;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        dataPointMean += (pow ((arr[i] - mean), 2)); 

    }

    int sampleVariance = dataPointMean/2;
    double sampleStandardDeviation = pow(sampleVariance, 1/2);
    cout << sampleStandardDeviation << endl;
    return sampleStandardDeviation;

}
```

Comment: `pow(sampleVariance, 1/2);`  -- That second argument isn't going to do what you think it will do. An `int` divided by an `int` gives you an `int`.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `stdDev` is expected to be able to handle more than two elements.

Comment: Also: please get into the habit of differentiating between *compilation* of the source code and *running* the compiled executable. C++ code isn't *ran* in the same sense as Python or Bash code.

Comment: And I'm reasonably convinced that what you're compiling on Mimir is something other than what you're compiling yourself. Double-check.

Comment: I suspect that you are not following the constraints of your assignment. The test on your school's server will probably assume that stdDev can be called with a `Person*` argument, which yours can not.

Comment: The code is correct except for incorrect usage of integer division and bad style concerning the use of `using std::*` : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dde4667ad6aecb8
As per @SamiHult suggestion: carefully read the docs for the assignment. The test system must provide a complete enough description of the input and output formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: the code provided is well-formed. It compiles correctly, though there is one mistake in the usage of `pow()` from `<cmath>` that leads to incorrect calculation results (different from those that you might expect). The problem most probably arises when your code meets the test system.

Proof of correctness:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dde4667ad6aecb8

> How would I begin to resolve this issue?

First, you need to understand the error message:

> Error: Cannot Convert ‘Person*’ To ‘double*’ For Argument ‘1’ to ‘Double stdDev(double[], int)’

This means that there is a function with the signature `double stdDev(Person*, int)`. However, there is no code that calls such a function. There only is an invocation of `stdDev(double*, int)`  in the line `double a = stdDev(people, ARRAY_SIZE);`. That means that the erroneous invocation comes from elsewhere, but the function is not defined *in your code*. This means that there is additional code that you can't see, most probably provided by the test system.

Another possibility is that you have a copy of the code with a modification that is escaping your attention. The modification is that instead of

```
double people[2];
double a = stdDev(people, ARRAY_SIZE);
```

you do:

```
Person people[2];
double a = stdDev(people, ARRAY_SIZE);
```

This triggers the error for obvious reasons. If you have been refactoring the code, it is highly probable that you've forgotten to update the function call line. Recheck the code carefully.

> What am I missing, or not understanding?

Read the task formulation closely. A well-formed test system should contain a complete enough description of the *input and output format*. You're likely to find out that the `stdDev()` function should take `Person[]` according to the input format.

---

The one mistake in the code provided is:

```
double sampleStandardDeviation = pow(sampleVariance, 1/2);
```

`1/2` is an expression that divides two integers and returns an integer as well, i.e. "integer division". Integer division returns the quotient, which in this case is `0`. That means you're calling `pow()` with an exponent of `0` and it always returns `1`. There are two common ways to resolve the issue:

- Explicitly cast one of the operands to a floating-point type: `(double)1/2` - this approach makes sense in case where the operand is an expression
- Specify a floating-point literal by adding `.0` or `.`: `1.0/2`

---

> When I attempt to run it on my local machine

Just to make sure you understand: C++ is a compiled language (as is the C language). The source code is first compiled into machine (binary) code, and only then the executable file is ran by the OS. Compilation (or "building") and execution are two distinct yet equally important phases of the execution of a C++ program.